# VBA for Copying Ranges from Multiple Sheets Into a New One

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My goal is to copy the following cells from all selected sheets, transform them into individual rows per sheet, and paste them into a newly created sheet within the selected workbook: C4, F3, C3, B2, C5, K3, D21, F4, D22:D120

There are several similar question on SO, but none deal with multiple ranges within a sheet, the selection of multiple sheets, and the transformation into tabular data with a different row per sheet. With the help of some existing threads and AI, I managed to cobble this code together, but it has several issues:

1. The new sheet it creates is in the workbook that the macro originates from, rather than the selected workbook.
2. It is only copy/paste/transforming the last selected sheet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub CopyPasteBudgetExpenses()
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim selectedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Create a new worksheet for pasting
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    TargetSheet.Name = "PastedValues"
    TargetRow = 1

    ' Set the starting column in the target sheet
    ColumnOffset = 1

    ' Loop through all selected sheets
    For Each selectedSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ' Create a new row in the target sheet for each sheet's values
        LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        TargetRow = LastRow + 1

        ' Copy and paste the specified cells from the selected sheet
        Set SourceRange = selectedSheet.Range("C4, F3, C3, B2, C5, K3, D21, F4, D22:D120")

        For Each cell In SourceRange
            TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ColumnOffset).Value = cell.Value
            ColumnOffset = ColumnOffset + 1
        Next cell

        ' Reset column offset for the next sheet
        ColumnOffset = 1
    Next selectedSheet

    ' AutoFit columns in the new worksheet for better visibility
    TargetSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook the macro is in, you probably want `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Use `MsgBox ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count` to validate the quantity of selected sheets.

Comment: You are adding a new worksheet, so that automatically becomes the selected sheet, effectively wiping out what was previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try. You must exclude the newly created worksheet from the loop.

```
' Loop through all selected sheets
For Each selectedSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If selectedSheet.Name <> TargetSheet.Name Then

        ' Create a new row in the target sheet for each sheet's values
        LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(TargetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        TargetRow = LastRow + 1

        ' Copy and paste the specified cells from the selected sheet
        Set SourceRange = selectedSheet.Range("C4, F3, C3, B2, C5, K3, D21, F4, D22:D120")

        For Each cell In SourceRange
            TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ColumnOffset).Value = cell.Value
            ColumnOffset = ColumnOffset + 1
        Next cell

        ' Reset column offset for the next sheet
        ColumnOffset = 1
    End If

Next selectedSheet
```

Good luck.